# how to use multselect field in django admin for filtering

Tags: django, django-models

I am using `multiselectfield` in my model to define one field and also register that model to `admin.py` when I am using that field in `list_filter` admin page not able to filter my data.

How can I use `multiselectfield` as well as use it for filters or is there any better way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Check [developer answer](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield/issues/59#issuecomment-284524337) in their GitHub issues. It is a bit old, but looks like this issue is still present, and is more a 'feature'.

You can use PostgreSQL [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield), or store values in separate related table linked by ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom filter to accomplish that.

Based on the docs multiselect storage a charfield with the options selected separated by commas
you can use the endswith to get when the user selects only one option, and the icontains to get when the user choose more than one option.

```
class MultiSelectFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.

    title = param_title
    parameter_name = param_name

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return ( ('option 1', 'Option 1'),
                     ('option 2', 'Option 2')) # tuple ('lookup_value', 'tittle_value in list filter')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(Q(**{
                f'{self.parameter_name}__iendswith': self.value()
            }) | Q(**{
                f'{self.parameter_name}__icontains': f'{self.value()},'
            }))
        return queryset
```